# How to use alternative js/browser engine with htmlunit instead of rhino?

Tags: java, junit, rhino, gecko, javascript-engine

Throughout my experiences with using htmlunit, I have slowly come to realize that htmlunit does not interact well with javascript.

The rhino js engine which htmlunit uses is most definitely the root cause of these issues, and I was wondering if it was possible to use something like geckodriver instead while still using htmlunit.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some facts

- HtmlUnit uses a slightly modified (improved) version of the Rhino engine
- the team behind HtmlUnit is working on an implementation based on (a slightly modified) Nashorn (the js engine from the jdk) but there is still a lot of work to do
- from the experience with the Nashorn task i can tell you that is is not simple to use a different engine but as for any other open source project feel free to provide patches
- HtmlUnit is a java only implementation, it is one of the benefits to have a browser simulation that works on many different platforms eg. you can simulate IE from a linux box

To make the long story short:

If you have problem with HtmlUnit's JavaScript support

- Read this [Submitting JavaScript bugs](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/submittingJSBugs.html)
- analyze you problem
- open a HtmlUnit issue [here](https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/submittingBugs.html), including a simple test case
- [optional] provide a patch

The development team behind is small but active. If you provide a simple test case, there is a good chance to get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's really cool that I got a response from you. Could you provide a link to where I can open htmlunit issues?

Comment: Have added a link to the issue tracker.